# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I have this method to compare to images that are in **xhdpi**  but giving me this error 
 **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()** here is code :

```
 private boolean CompareImages(ImageView im1, ImageView im2){

            boolean bool = false;
            int check = 0, v1, v2, v3, ev1, ev2, ev3;
            Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable)im1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)im2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();


            for(int j = 50; j < 160; j = j + 50){
                int pixel = bitmap1.getPixel(j,j);
                int pixel2 = bitmap2.getPixel(j,j);

                int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

                v1 = (redValue + greenValue + blueValue)/3;

                int redValue1 = Color.red(pixel2);
                int blueValue2 = Color.blue(pixel2);
                int greenValue2 = Color.green(pixel2);

                ev1 = (redValue1 + greenValue2 + blueValue2)/3;

                if(v1 == ev1){
                    bool = true;
                } else{
                    bool = false;
                }
            }

            return bool;
}
```

here logcat:

```
03-31 10:53:45.192: E/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     ... 11 more
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1158)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1107)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.example.gusetheplace.ConductQuiz2.CompareImages(ConductQuiz2.java:794)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     at com.example.gusetheplace.ConductQuiz2.onClick_rb4(ConductQuiz2.java:630)
03-31 11:29:33.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1574):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Could you post your full logcat please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're are iterating over `int j = 50; j < 160; j = j + 50`, without checking the real size of the images.

You should use `Bitmap.getHeight()` and `Bitmap.getWidth()` in order to call `Bitmap.getPixel(x,y)` with valid coordinates.

Comment: Yes. The Image Pixels are less then index in loop